# cookie not setting properly in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I have created basic login setup based upon cookie alone in codeigniter.
like this

```
class Display extends CI_Controller {
public function Display() {
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index() {
    //var_dump($_COOKIE);
    if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])){
        redirect('home')
    }else{
        redirect('display/login');
    }

}
public function login() {
    //var_dump($_COOKIE);
    if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])){
        $this->load->view('home');
    }else{
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
                    //some validation
        setcookie("user",$username,time()+60*60*24*30);
        redirect('home');
    }
}
```

}

In the home controller i check for the cookies to access the page

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
public function Home() {
    parent::__construct();
    //var_dump(get_cookie("user"));exit;
     if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]) == false){
     redirect('display/login');
    }
}
```

}

The problem i am facing here is i cant get cookie in the constructor of the class. i need check for cookie in class before accessing any of the function in the class. what will be the proper way to do it ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you attempting to get the cookie in the same request as you set it?

Comment: @diggersworld basically ya i use get_cookie() .and check those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't assign the [`path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) parameter of the cookie, so it gets the path of the page it's assigning it and results to be `/login` or something similar and it won't be sent to other parts of your page like `/home`, or simply the root. Change the `setcookie()` like to somethig like this:

```
setcookie("user",$username,time()+60*60*24*30, '/'); // notice the added path at the end
```

Also anyone can set cookies in their client, relaying only their existence as authentication is not secure at all, anyone can change what their `user` cookie holds.

Comment: at this point i didn't bother about security of the project its pretty basic.And Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using CodeIgniter's own implementation (Cookie_Helper): http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CodeIgniter User Guide Version 2.2.0: Input Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/input.html).

Use `$this->input->set_cookie()` to set cookie and `$this->input->cookie()` to get cookie